# GIT recuperar arquivos (git reset --hard HEAD)

Tags: git, bitbucket

Sou um pouco inexperiente com GIT. Estava trabalhando em uma branch, porem, queria receber algumas atualizações na branch master, porem `git pull` falhou, pois havia alterações não comitadas. Então acabei utilizado o comando `git reset --hard HEAD`. Mas havia esquecido das alterações não comitadas na outra branch, além daquelas que eu queria descartar.
A pergunta é, Há como recuperar tais arquivos? Ali tem várias horas de trabalho. Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Olha, detesto trazer esse tipo de notícia mas até onde sei não existe nada que possa ser feito em relação a alterações não commitadas no git. Se você estava usando um IDE há uma chance de encontrar essas alterações no histórico local.

Comment: É, eu já imaginava :´(

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando o NetBeans. Consigo recuperar completamente os arquivos novos, mas parece que as modificações em arquivos existentes não. Mas isso já é tipo uns 65% ou 70% do conteúdo perdido. Valeu.

Comment: Oi mau humor. Funciona em arquivos existentes também, basta clicar com o botão direito e visualizar as versões em _Local History_ , encontre a versão deseja e reverta o arquivo. Mais tarde posto uma resposta com calma.

Comment: Sim, eu percebi isso depois, tirando uma ou outra alteração, consegui recuperar tudo. Agradeço mais uma vez :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível. De acordo com a documentação do [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

> git-reset - Reset current HEAD to the specified state

Tradução: move o ponteiro (o `HEAD`) do seu último commit para o commit desejado -- no caso, o próprio `HEAD`. Quando você roda o comando com a opção `--hard`, todas as alterações pendentes (também chamado de *working tree*) são descartadas.

No caso específico do seu problema, era possível ter rodado o comando `git stash` para "guardar" suas alterações sem necessariamente comitá-las, baixar as alterações do `master`, reaplicar suas alterações com `git stash apply` e resolver os eventuais conflitos.

Comment: Ok, valeu pela dica, mas dessa vez o histórico do NetBeans me salvou :D.

Comment: @mauhumor Boa. :)

Comment: É possível procurar por commits que estão fora da árvore: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216462/64969