# Reverter um git reset hard

Tags: git

Fiz umas coisas erradas ao fazer alguns teste e apaguei todo meus arquivos tanto no local quanto no github, como faço para reverter e não perder tudo?

os comando que utilizei e creio que foi o que bagunçou tudo foram:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages

git reset --hard

git commit --allow-empty -m "Initializing gh-pages branch"

git push origin gh-pages

git checkout master
```

Comment: Primeiramente recomendo **NÃO RODE O GC**, segundamente recomendo esperar uma resposta com bastante calma...

Comment: Eu usei isso para reverter um branch local que eu tinha apagado... estou pesquisando o como

Comment: Algo aqui ajuda? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3640764

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ja tentei algumas coisas não deu certo, acho que perdi tudo mesmo =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrumar esses dados começa com o [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck). Esse comando verifica a base de dados do git, para saber se está tudo certo.

> seu nome é derivado das ferramentas usadas para verificar a sanidade em sistemas de arquivos, [File System Consistency checK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck)

Temos várias opções para esse comando do git:

- `--unreachable` para objetos não alcançáveis de maneira tradicional
- `--no-reflogs` para ignorar o `reflog`
- `--full` manda o git procurar em outros cantos além do padrão

O seguinte comando usa esses argumentos para procurar coisas não alcançáveis, ignorando o `reflog` e de tudo que é canto:

```
git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs --full
```

Comment: Erick, só vi durante a escrita da minha resposta que você tinha tentado essas alternativas. Se não for útil, me avise que eu removo a resposta

Comment: Rodei esse comando e me retorou alguns SHA

Comment: O problema é que deletei a branch aonde eu tinha comitado tudo e dado push, tem algum jeito de recuperar essa branch?

Comment: Bem, talvez algum desses SHA1 seja o do commit do branch master original...

Comment: Opa aguenta ai que acho q consegui recuperar com sua dica, vou avaliar aqui

Comment: @Erick claro que sim, você pode pedir para o git listar o que ele sabe de cada SHA1 desses. Se for um commit, basta dar um `git checkout -b lucky-restore-jeff <luckysha1>`, que então o branch `lucky-restore-jeff` apontará para esse commit

Comment: Então uma dessas SHA era um commit ai dei o comando git cherry-pick "SHA"  e voltou os arquivos ...

Comment: Fico feliz com o resultado o/ Mais cuidado da próxima vez. Sempre que vejo algo desse tipo eu fico passando mal, é muito desespero

Comment: So achei um pouco confusa sua escrita na resposta, não sei se vc é Brasileiro talvez possa ser isso rs, mas sua dica foi o que me ajudou, obrigado.

Comment: @Erick sou brasileiro e ainda escrevi informal demais. Perdão às gírias e expressões locais, vou tentar reformular em um outro momento para uma linguagem mais adequada