# Sem querer reverti (undo) , como avançar a frente?

Tags: git, github

Estava fazendo uma reversão de uma versão, mas sem querer apertei 2 vezes seguidas em undo no git dekstop, Mas os arquivos que criei antes foram todos pro espaço. Muita lógica e tempo perdidos. Há a possibilidade de recuperar esses arquivos ?

Comment: Tem acesso a linha de comando?

Comment: Os arquivos estavam já commitados? Ou ainda estavam _untracked_?

Comment: Sim. Foram comitados,.. tenho sim acesso ao bash

Comment: Creio ser um problema semelhante ao desta questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216458/64969 .

Comment: infelzmente não consegui abstrair a solução. Sou novo com o git. Listeis as sha. Porém não consigo recupera-las

Comment: Tem `gitk`? Para cada SHA1 obtido, dê `gitk <SHA1-obtido>` para tentar dar uma dica visual do que está acontecendo

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Consegui resolver meu problema... Parece que eu tinha morrido depois disso. Mas agora me sinto leve novamente.. Já pensou mais de 1000 linhas perdidas ?.. Isso vai me ajudar a não cometer mais esse erro

Comment: sei como é, já precisei fazer isso também. Vou marcar como duplicata daquela questão que linkei, pois no meu entender foi a resposta dela que te guiou até sua solução

Comment: Sim.. Foi através dela que eu consegui resolver